# Assign unique alphabetic sequential IDs in lift

Tags: scala, lift

I'm trying to create four letter sequential UIDs using the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils

val serial = new AtomicLong(0) 
val radix = 'Z' - 'A'  
def next ()= {

val prefix = java.lang.Long.toString(serial.incrementAndGet(),radix).toUpperCase()

 val mystring = StringUtils.leftPad(prefix, 10, 'A')
 mystring.padTo(4, "A")
 }
```

The code doesn't work and I get this error : object lang3 is not a member of package org.apache.commons

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Instead of just saying the "code doesn't work" say what _does_ happen, including any errors or exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't included the org.apache.commons.lang3 library, add the following to your `build.sbt` file:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.3.2"`